# Using HTML in A Form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am trying to create a form that accepts **HTML**. So that when I type `<br>` or use `divs` it understands and populated my content block accordingly. Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Here's the form I am using if that helps:

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@daily) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Is not clear. Where do you want to write divs and brs?

Comment: Sorry about that. This is the form I fill out for a blog post on a webpage. Instead of typing text into the content input - I'd like to paste some HTML. So that way when I press submit, the page where I view the blog post is formatted accordingly. However now it just shows the html as text. It isn't processing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<%= f.input :content %>` with `<%= f.text_area :content %>`. That doesn't do much but make a multi-line input area (looks better). However, when you display the data on your webpage (i.e. after you submit the form), you can put something like this:

```
<p>@daily.content.html_safe</p>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Ryan!

Comment: No problem. Now, make sure that this form isn't public facing. Because people could input some `<script>` tags and (IIRC) that JavaScript would run and can be dangerous.

Comment: Why you don't have a textarea also using simple form (input instead of textarea)? Is your field a text (not a string) in the database?